# Close current tab and open new one selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to do the following: Navigate to a specific url then in the second loop, I would like to close the existing tab for some reasons of getting information correctly (as a new start)
So I would like to open a new tab and close the previous tab
This is my try

```
 If f = True Then
            ''.Refresh
            .ExecuteScript "window.open('');"
            .SwitchToNextWindow
            .Windows.Item(.Windows.Count - 1).Close
            ''.SwitchToPreviousWindow
            ''.Close
'            .SwitchToNextWindow
            End If
            .Get sBaseURL
```

I got an error after cloing the tab and when trying to naviagte the url for the second time
`NoSuchWindowError`

I could solve the first part by creating a new tab and naviagting to the new tab

```
   If f = True Then
    Stop
    
    .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", sBaseURL
    .SwitchToNextWindow
    ''.Windows.Item(.Windows.Count - 1).Close
    
    End If
```

But I couldn't close the previous window (tab)

```
.Windows.Item(.Windows.Count - 1).Close
```

As when trying to activate this line of closing the previous window, I got the error `NoSuchWindowError`

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem by using these lines

```
    If f = True Then
    .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", sBaseURL
    .SwitchToNextWindow
    .Windows(1).Close
    .Windows(1).Activate
    End If
```

But I welcome any ideas or solutions